# How to reach out to company that previously offered me a job?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

A year ago I interviewed with Company A and Company B at the same time. Company A offered me a contract position, which I accepted. A few weeks later, Company B offered me a position, which I declined, saying I already accepted a position elsewhere.

Now my contract with Company A is ending and I am looking for new employment. Company B is currently hiring for positions that I am interested in, so I would like to interview with them again if possible. How should I best reach out to Company B?

Edit: I would like to know if there is anything I should do in addition to just normally applying

Answer (score 6):

While there are some good suggestions here, I think you would have the best chance of success not by applying as if you had no history with the company, nor by applying as normal, but mentioning the previous offer in a covering email.

You ***could*** consider approaching HR, but personally, I would approach someone who interviewed me, especially if I would be reporting to them.

I would want my soon to be new boss thinking “we interviewed this guy last year and really wanted him. Let’s not risk losing him again. Let’s get him on board ASAP”.

I don’t know your profession, but as a software engineer, I often see us hire good people, so as not to lose them to the market,  and worry later about where to use them.

Since the company currently has openings that match you, I am sure that they  will want to have you on  board.

Just make it a friendly “hello, remember me? I interviewed you last year and you made an offer. Unfortunately, by that time I had accepted something else, and felt hon(u)r bound not to let them down. Now I am free and notice that you have some openings similar to the position which you offered me last year, and wondered if you would still be interested in me”. That should set things rolling nicely.

Comment: I had this exact situation and did exactly what is suggested here.  I started work at Company B a month later.  This is great advice!

Comment: That's great to hear. If you had posted your story first, it would have made an even better answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

If they said something like: contact us if you change your mind - then do that.

Otherwise - apply by normal means.

Comment: It would not harm mentioning in the cover letter that the OP had an offer from them a year back. May ease the interviewing process.